# Change UITableView color automatically?

Tags: ios, uitableview, show-hide

I am trying to hide my UITableView conditionally based on an if statement.

Now I have the following code and when I load the app, it checks the condition and this works and when I press the Reload button, it checks and it works.

I also have a ViewWillAppear statement, which would work if I change the view and come back to the TableView again.

Now my question is what void or method do I need to make this automatic - ie without having to press a button or change views??

Now the code shows the 3 methods I have, and they all more or less have the same code, to show what I have thus far.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
//self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(insertNewObject:)];
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;

// Change Color of TableView if Empty
if (![[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] > 0 ) {
    //I know there are two statements here that can work individually from each other, but either of them would be a relevant matter.
    [_tableView setAlpha:1.0];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
}
else if ([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] > 0 ) {
    //I know there are two statements here that can work individually from each other, but either of them would be a relevant matter.
    [_tableView setAlpha:1.0];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    NSLog (@"");
}
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];

// Change Color of TableView if Empty
if (![[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] > 0 ) {
    //I know there are two statements here that can work individually from each other, but either of them would be a relevant matter.
    [_tableView setAlpha:1.0];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
}
else if ([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] > 0 ) {
    //I know there are two statements here that can work individually from each other, but either of them would be a relevant matter.
    [_tableView setAlpha:1.0];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    NSLog (@"");
}
}




-(IBAction)ReloadAction{

// Change Color of TableView if Empty
if (![[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] > 0 ) {
    //I know there are two statements here that can work individually from each other, but either of them would be a relevant matter.
    [_tableView setAlpha:1.0];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor purpleColor]];
}
else if ([[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] count] > 0 ) {
    //I know there are two statements here that can work individually from each other, but either of them would be a relevant matter.
    [_tableView setAlpha:1.0];
    [self.tableView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    NSLog (@"");
}
[_tableView reloadData];
//[_tableView performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(reloadData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

Cheers Jeff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out

I added that if statement to where the + sign is defined and where the delete method is set in the code:-)

Thanks Anyway:-)

Comment: Also, check out the fetched results controller delegate, this method in particular: - (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller.  It notifies you of a change.  You can replace the reloadAction with this.

Comment: Yeah I will keep that in mind to check that out, I just tried it with the statement I displayed above and it does not do automatically. I will need to look into that:-) Thanks.

Comment: Good luck.  Make sure you set your fetchedResultsController delegate to the class that implements controllerDidChangeContent ... probably 'self'.